# Se envian siempre los mismos registros $_POST aunque tengan diferente identificador

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo la siguiente situación para mi proyecto de la Universidad:

Necesito enviar a un controlador algunos registros de una tabla `html` que esta dentro de un formulario. Dichos registros vienen de una tabla llamada **solicitudes** y son llamados mediante una consulta y `foreach`. Hasta ahí todo bien se muestran todos los registros, pero son registros de una 'solicitud de préstamo' cuyas acciones son **Aprobar** o **Rechazar** la solicitud.

Cada solicitud tiene, por ende, un **id** único y un **número de serie** único. Entonces cuando escojo la acción **Aprobar**, se debería enviar la aprobación para la solicitud.

Como es un sistema de pruebas, ya se ingresaron 4 diferentes solicitudes.

A la hora de aprobar la primera no hubo ningún problema. Se envió al controlador y se insertaron los datos en la tabla **prestamos**.

El problema es que cuando quiero **Aprobar** otra solicitud, siempre se intenta la solicitud que ya fue ingresada, y así pasa con las otras solicitudes.

Hice validación en el controlador para que no se repitan datos y por ende me arroja el error

> La solicitud no fue procesada ya que fue ingresada a la base de datos con el número de serie 00001

Y así sucede con cualquier otra solicitud...

He probado muchos códigos y sigue haciendo lo mismo.

Hice `var_dump($_POST)` y ahí pude darme cuenta que son los mismos campos de la primera solicitud que sigue enviando...

A continuación les muestro el código relevante del `html` y `javascript` con `Ajax` para que puedan orientarme.

Por favor tomen en cuenta que el código de la tabla `html` está dentro de un formulario y que estoy trabajando con una plantilla administrativa (adminlte)

**De antemano muchas gracias!!!**

```
<form action="../c/ctrlp.php" method="POST">
// resto del codigo no relevante ya que aqui se encuentra los thead, la consulta con el foreach y todo funciona bien...

<tr style="color:black">          
    <td> 
      <!-- Botón de Aprobar -->
      <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm d-inline mx-1" onclick="aprobarSolicitud(this)" data-numero-serie="<?php echo $solicitud['numero_serie']; ?>">Aprobar</button>
      <!-- Botón de Rechazar -->
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm d-inline mx-1" onclick="rechazarSolicitud(this)" data-numero-serie="<?php echo $solicitud['numero_serie']; ?>">Rechazar</button>      
    </td>
      <td style="color:red"><center><?php echo $counterTC; ?></center></td>
      <td class="warning"  name="id">
        <center><?php echo $idSolicitud; ?></center>
        <input type="hidden"  name="id" value="<?php echo $idSolicitud; ?>">
      </td>
      <td class="warning"  name="numero_serie">
        <center><?php echo $numero_serie; ?>
        <input type="hidden"  name="numero_serie" value="<?php echo $numero_serie; ?>">
      </center>
      </td>
      <td class="warning" name="fecha_solicitud">
        <center><?php echo $fecha_solicitud; ?></center>
        <input type="hidden" name="fecha_solicitud" value="<?php echo $fecha_solicitud; ?>">
      </td>
      <td class="danger"><center><?php echo $estado; ?></center></td>
      <td class="warning" name="nombreu">
        <center><?php echo $nombreu; ?></center>
        <input type="hidden" name="nombreu" value="<?php echo $nombreu; ?>">
      </td>
      <td class="warning" name="nombrec">
        <center><?php echo $nombrec; ?></center>
        <input type="hidden" name="nombrec" value="<?php echo $nombrec; ?>">
      </td>
      <td class="warning" name="dpi">
        <center><?php echo $dpi; ?></center>
        <input type="hidden" name="dni" value="<?php echo $dni; ?>">
      </td>
      <td class="warning" name="direccion_casa">
        <center><?php echo $direccion_casa; ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="direccion_casa" value="<?php echo $direccion_casa; ?>">
      </center></td>
      <td class="warning"><center><?php echo $direccion_trabajo; ?></center></td>
      <td class="warning" name="phone">
        <center><?php echo $phone; ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>">
      </center></td> 
      <td class="warning" name="codigo_credito">
        <center><?php echo $codigo_credito; ?></center>
        <input type="hidden" name="codigo_credito" value="<?php echo $codigo_credito; ?>">
      </td>
      <td class="success" name="tipo_credito">
        <center><?php echo $tipo_credito; ?></center>
        <input type="hidden" name="tipo_credito" value="<?php echo $tipo_credito; ?>">
      </td>
      <td class="warning"  name="forma_credito">
        <center><?php echo $forma_credito; ?></center>
        <input type="hidden" name="forma_credito" value="<?php echo $forma_credito; ?>">
      </td>
      <td class="success" name="interes">
        <center><?php echo $interes; ?></center>
        <input type="hidden" name="interes" value="<?php echo $interes; ?>">
      </td>
      <td class="success" name="credito">
        <center><?php echo $credito; ?></center>
        <input type="hidden" name="credito" value="<?php echo $credito; ?>">
      </td>   
      <td class="warning" name="monto_recibir">
        <center><?php echo $monto_recibir; ?></center>
        <input type="hidden" name="monto_recibir" value="<?php echo $monto_recibir; ?>">
      </td>
      <td class="success" name="cuota">
        <center><?php echo $cuota; ?></center>
        <input type="hidden" name="cuota" value="<?php echo $cuota; ?>">
      </td>
      <td class="success" name="dias">
        <center><?php echo $dias; ?></center>
        <input type="hidden" name="dias" value="<?php echo $dias; ?>">
      </td>                           

</tr>
```

Este es el JS Con Ajax

```
<!-- SCRIPT PARA LOS BOTONES DE RECHAZAR O ACEPTAR -->
<script>
  function aprobarSolicitud(button) {
    var numeroSerie = $(button).data('numero-serie');
    var idSolicitud = $('#id-' + numeroSerie).val();
    var fechaSolicitud = $('#fecha-solicitud-' + numeroSerie).val();
    var nombreu = $('#nombreu-' + numeroSerie).val();
    var nombrec = $('#nombrec-' + numeroSerie).val();
    var dpi = $('#dni-' + numeroSerie).val();
    var direccionCasa = $('#direccion-casa-' + numeroSerie).val();
    var phone = $('#phone-' + numeroSerie).val();
    var codigoCredito = $('#codigo-credito-' + numeroSerie).val();
    var tipoCredito = $('#tipo-credito-' + numeroSerie).val();
    var formaCredito = $('#forma-credito-' + numeroSerie).val();
    var interes = $('#interes-' + numeroSerie).val();
    var credito = $('#credito-' + numeroSerie).val();
    var montoRecibir = $('#monto-recibir-' + numeroSerie).val();
    var cuota = $('#cuota-' + numeroSerie).val();
    var dias = $('#dias-' + numeroSerie).val();

    $.ajax({
      url: '../c/ctrlp.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        id: idSolicitud,
        numero_serie: numeroSerie,
        fecha_solicitud: fechaSolicitud,
        nombreu: nombreu,
        nombrec: nombrec,
        dni: dni,
        direccion_casa: direccionCasa,
        phone: phone,
        codigo_credito: codigoCredito,
        tipo_credito: tipoCredito,
        forma_credito: formaCredito,
        interes: interes,
        credito: credito,
        monto_recibir: montoRecibir,
        cuota: cuota,
        dias: dias
      },
      success: function(response) {
        // Manejar la respuesta del servidor aquí
        console.log(response); // Mostrar la respuesta en la consola
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        // Manejar errores de la solicitud aquí
        console.log('Error en la solicitud AJAX: ' + error);
      }
    });
  }

  function rechazarSolicitud(button) {
    var numeroSerie = $(button).data('numero-serie');

    $.ajax({
      url: '../c/ctrl_prestamos.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: { numero_serie: numeroSerie },
      success: function(response) {
        // Manejar la respuesta del servidor aquí
        console.log(response); // Mostrar la respuesta en la consola
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        // Manejar errores de la solicitud aquí
        console.log('Error en la solicitud AJAX: ' + error);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

**Datos adicionales:**

Ya probé con otros `JS`, el cambiar botones, utilizar por medio de 'id' y todo sigue igual...

No envio el **ctrlp.php** porque ahí si recibe los `POST` pero solo de los mismos datos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te voy a dejar unas sugerencias pero solo teniendo en cuenta algunos puntos claves y así evitamos confusiones si repetimos todo el código...

- En `JS` estás tratando de acceder a unos elementos con `id` inexistente, por ejemplo:

```
//No existe este elemento en el código que muestras
var idSolicitud = $('#id-' + numeroSerie).val();
//De ser así, al menos uno de los elementos debería verse así por ejemplo
<input id="id-<?php echo $solicitud['numero_serie']; ?>">
```

- No es necesario usar la etiqueta `form` si vas a recoger los valores individuales en `JS` para luego enviarlos a través de `ajax`.
- No te hagas líos innecesarios. Veo que todos los `input` están ocultos. Si no modificas datos, lo mejor es enviar solo el `id` de la solicitud para aprobarla o rechazarla.
- Cuando estés maquetando el `HTML` de la tabla, puedes pasar como parámetro el `id` de la solicitud a las funciones de los botones (*o el número de serie, si lo prefieres*).

```
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm d-inline mx-1" onclick="aprobarSolicitud(<?php echo $idSolicitud; ?>)">Aprobar</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm d-inline mx-1" onclick="rechazarSolicitud(<?php echo $idSolicitud; ?>)">Rechazar</button>
```

- Luego en `JS` recibes este parámetro en la respectiva función.

```
function aprobarSolicitud(idSolicitud) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        data: { idSolicitud: idSolicitud},
        ...
    }
}

function rechazarSolicitud(idSolicitud) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        data: { idSolicitud: idSolicitud},
        ...
    }
}
```

A grandes rasgos veo esas falencias. Trata de modificarlas y se te hará mucho más fácil el manejo de las solicitudes previamente registradas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, fijate que antes no estaba encapsulada la tabla html en un form, pero como dije he probado alrededor de 5 js e incluso originalmente lo tenia mediante un select al escoger una de las 2 opciones enviaba los datos, pero no funcionaba, antes del anterior a este tenia un id=' id ' y un name='id'  algo asi para todos los campos y tampoco...

var numeroSerie = $(button).data('numero-serie');
  $.ajax({
    url: '../c/ctrl_prestamos.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: { id: idSolicitud,
            numero_serie: numeroSerie,
por ejemplo asi estaba antes...

Comment: Es complejo darte solución exacta porque falta contexto y porque es mucho código para analizar, pero si te apegas a la última parte de la respuesta creo que debería funcionar. Tal como lo mencioné, si no modificas otros datos, lo único que necesitas pasar al controlador  es el id de la solicitud.

Comment: muchas gracias he estado viendo de momento no he podido solucionar el problema, vere si cambiando completamente la estructura se puede, muchas gracias

Comment: Debo agredecerte me encaminaste muy bien al problema , quite el id y el numero de serie quedo establecido para aceptar o rechazar en los botones y mediante ajax, sin necesidad de ir llamando uno a uno, aunque quite los input y el formulario porque originalmente lo tenia, el JS lo tenia mal en un inicio y me desespere y trate de incluirlo dentro de un form, pero realmente tu ayuda me encamino muy bien a ordenar bien el codigo y asi enviar solicitud por solicitud. Muchas gracias nueamente!!